# Parse a string from a sensor containing 3 floats

Tags: java, sensors, temperature

I'm trying to parse information from a temperature sensor.
Sensors sends a String with the format:

```
Temp: 1   388  2   358  3   200?    
Temp: 1   388  2   200?  3   200?
```

(First String contains a valid channel 2 sample and channel 3 disconnected, and second String has channel 2 and 3 disconnected).

I need to parse those "dat" which is a float without the dot, and I cant use String.split() because if the sensor doesn't detects anything it adds a '?' to the end of "dat".
Output should be:

```
Temp[0]= 38.8
Temp[1]= 35.8
Temp[2]= 20.0
```

Also I need to parse that '?' to say if a channel it's disconnected.

Comment: Rarely have I heard a problem beg for regular expressions as loud as this one... What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would help if you'd give *actual* sample data instead of lines with "dat" in. It's still unclear why split wouldn't work for you...

Comment: Can you give some real samples?

Comment: Updated with real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to use split() to solve this problem, and did't see anything wrong you say.

```
public static void parseData(String data) {
    String[] args = data.split("\\s+");
    for (int i=2; i<7; i+=2) {
        if (args[i].charAt(args[i].length() - 1) == '?') {
            args[i] = args[i].substring(0, args[i].length() - 1);
        }
        double val = Double.parseDouble(args[i]) / 10;
        System.out.println("Temp[" + (i-1)/2 + "]= " + val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put a '+' in the Split, thats why I dont used String.split(). And your '?' identification is great!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most easy approach would be to use `String.split("\\s")` this will provide an array of Strings. For example:

```
 Temp: 1   388  2   358  3   200?  => {"Temp:", "1", "388", "2", "358", "3", "200?"}
```

Knowing that the first temperature should be the 3rd column you can start processing from there. For obtaining numeric values you can use `Integer.parse(...)`. For floats you can divide by 10. You can check whether it has a trailing "?" with `String.endsWith(...)`. For more complicated processing you can use different regexs. More information [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) about regex in java.

How do you receive your input? Where do you read it from? A good and simple solution could be the [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(sensorStream);
while (line.hasNext()) {
    line.next(); // Temp:
    line.next(); // #

    int firstReading = line.nextInt(); // 388
    float realFirstReading = firstReading/10.0; // 38.8

    line.next(); // #
    int secondReading = line.nextInt(); // 358
    float realSecondReading = secondReading/10.0 // 35.8

    line.next(); // #
    int thirdReading = line.nextInt(); // 200
    float realThirdReading = thirdReading / 10.0; // 20.0
    // do what you will with it
}
```

If you need further help, do leave a comment...